# Error 405 sending HTTP Post request from Android to C# Webservice

Tags: c#, android, rest, http, post

I try to send HTTP Post Request from an Android application to a C# RESTful web service.
For some reason I get a response code 405 as soon as it's connected.

If I try to send POST Request using a C# client that I made, the code works fine and I get a response successfully.

The code from Android (running on a service ofcourse):

```
String url = "http://myurl.com/Service1.svc/login/2";
String postDataParams = "{"username":"Ryrud","password":"Pups"}";

//Connect
            httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));
            int responseCode = httpcon.getResponseCode();
            Log.d("zzz", "RCode: " + responseCode); // Getting in log: "RCode: 405"
            httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpcon.connect();

//Post data
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpcon.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(postDataParams);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
```

RESTful Webservice code:

```
[OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "login/{id}")]
           login login(string id, login userpass);
```

Comment: Have you try to send your POST using Postman or other tools like this? It sounds to me that you are posting to an other endpoint on your service (and that endpoint does not have POST method allowed)

Comment: `wr.close();`. Remove that. It will close the socket too.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ask for a response code before you write the data to the outputstream.

Comment: i know that i have to ask for the response code after, the thing is that the result is the same so i tried to see if id get a different one as soon as i open the connection which happens either way.